# How can SSH.NET on Windows 10 start a process on our remote Linux box that stays running?

Tags: .net, linux, ssh, ssh.net

This code blocks until the Linux process ends itself:

```
cSSH.Connect()
cSSH.RunCommand("<our path>linux_process”)  <<< BLOCKS UNTIL linux_process ENDS ITSELF
cSSH.Disconnect()
cSSH.Dispose()
```

So, we then put “&” at end of RunCommand string; it doesn’t block RunCommand but prematurely ends the Linux process when app returns from the function that called .RunCommand to start Linux process:

```
cSSH.Connect()
cSSH.RunCommand("<our path>linux_process &”)  
cSSH.Disconnect()
cSSH.Dispose()

return      <<<<<<  CAUSES linux_process TO IMMEDIATELY END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just start a .NET thread that calls SSH.NET .RunCommand(  ) which blocks until Linux executable ends itself, at which point .RunCommand() returns and the .NET thread continues and, in my case, ends itself by simply returning.

I wonder why the downvote.